# regexp for preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to build a pattern to exchange integer numbers which are the only thing on the line

If there is a word on the same line as the integer I do not want to change anything.

I tried `$pattern = '/(.)[0-9][0-9](.)/';`
but this doesn't work well for me

and when I try for example `$pattern = '/1(.)2(.)3(.)/';` it will replace the only single numbers which I will put in pattern

I want to replace example subject of this

```
subject = "
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
"
```

the numbers must be integer not decimal and amouth of them are random but there musn't be any text on the same line as the number?

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to replace?

Comment: I want to replace the random INTEGER numbers with are without text in the same line        lets say the html output code will be <html>1<br>2<br>3</html> so i want this integer numbers to replace and the example of with i won't replace will be <html>1 kakm<br>2 sept<br>3 hsss</html>

Comment: @WebtranslateZapraszamy yeah, we got that. But what do you want to replace them **with**?

Comment: i have got replacement    <php? $replacements[0] = '";$balue="'; ?>        this work   the only thing i havent is regex code to parse this integer numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is multi-line mode `m`. If you use it `^` matches at the beginning and `$` matches at the end of each line. Then use `\d+` for an arbitrarily long integer number:

```
/^[ \t]*\d+[ \t]*$/m
```

The `[ \t]*` allow an arbitrary number of spaces and tabs in addition to the number. Note that this will remove the whitespace along with the number. If you want to keep the whitespace, use

```
/^([ \t]*)\d+([ \t]*)$/m
```

And change your replacement string to

```
$1yourReplacementString$2
```

**EDIT:**

I realize now that you don't have line breaks, as in `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n` but `<br>` tags. That makes it a bit more difficult. Something like this should cover most cases:

```
~((?:^|<br[ ]*/?>)[ \t]*)\d+([ \t]*(?:$|<br\b))~
```

Again, you need to add `$1` and `$2` around your replacement string to not remove the `<br>` tags.

But as Andy said, HTML should not be dealt with using regular expressions. Either use the built-in DOM module provided by PHP, or some 3rd party library like [this one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net).

Comment: /^\d+$/m doesn't work for me      in example of php code 
<?php $pattern = '/^\d+$/m'; $replacement = ''; $subject = "1<br> 2 <br>3<br> abcdef1"; echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject); ?>  it still output the number 1 2 3 and abcdef1    and i want to remove 1 2 3 from that

Comment: Ah right, so you have whitespace in there as well. That doesn't count as "numbers are the only thing on the line" for me ;). I'll edit the answer though

Comment: hmm i give up guys  but thanks for answer i couldnt figure it out /^([ \t]*)\d+([ \t]*)$/m  and /^[ \t]*\d+[ \t]*$/m doesnt work for me sory for time waste i will try to preg match another webpage to get their variables

Comment: @WebtranslateZapraszamy oh damn, I realise now that your line breaks aren't actual line break characters but `<br>` HTML tags. That changes a lot. I'll edit my answer once more.

Comment: thanks  now is working well for me  .I know that i should out of html tags    but i am doing it after preg replace   using php snoopy.class but yesterday i made a relly long script with multiple preg replace   everythink on the site and add variable before some texts and then i input those variables into the new script with while and echo sql update for zen-cart system   and it automatickly add those variables into the tables;]         huh i am finally done  thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Regexes are not a magic wand that are the answer to every programming problem.

In this case, sounds like you want to actually be using `explode()` to break apart your subject on `\n`, then manipulate the lines as an array, then recreating the subject with `implode()`.  It's much easier to deal with two lines when they are `$lines[$x]` and `$lines[$y]`.

Further, if the lines are coming from HTML, then you don't want to be using regular expressions to parse the HTML.  Instead, you want to use the PHP DOM module.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: both of you have got righ that i should use PHP DOM now i realize that i made it wrong way i should been using dom module would made this shorter and fastest            checked it already thanks